# Spark Python error “FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified”

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run `pyspark` on my local computer. I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 30, in sparkTest with SparkContext("local", "PySparkWordCount") as sc:
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark-2.2.0-py3.5.egg\pyspark\context.py", line 115, in __init__

SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark-2.2.0-py3.5.egg\pyspark\context.py", line 283, in _ensure_initialized

SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark-2.2.0-py3.5.egg\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 80, in launch_gateway

proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, env=env)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code
```

Comment: Did you check the usual suspects? `JAVA_HOME`, `PATH` etc. Does `context.py` exist in that folder?

Comment: @philantrovert Yeah I have already checked `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`. I can't find a context.py but there's a contextlib.py Can you tell me what is context.py and what are it's contents?

Comment: [`context.py`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/context.py) deals with creating SparkContext and takes care of other tasks that need to be done. Check `SPARK_HOME` as well.

Comment: @philantrovert I have already set and rechecked the environment variables `SPARK_HOME`,  `JAVA_HOME`, `HADOOP_HOME`, `PYTHONPATH`, `PATH`. `context.py` exisits in the pyspark folder(previously I checked the wrong folder). Do you have an idea what else could be the problem here?

Comment: If the verified the system environment variables and it is still not working, check if your jvm (64 or 32)bit version is compatible with your machine.